# allocating memory to an object of a class

Tags: java

I have a list with class objects say

```
List a[10];

class Hello extends abc implement xyz
{ 
String mesg1;
String mesg2;
Object c;
Goodbye d;
// also their getter setters
}
```

a[5] contains objects of Hello class

I have to copy object Instance at postion 1 then do some changes in mesg1 and mesg2  and insert it in the same list in the end.I m trying to do so, but as we know its only the reference that is stored there so i end up changing the mesg1 and mesg2 at position 1 too.

any suggestions ?
 i tried using clone() but cannot make changes to this class or the Hello class.

Comment: If you're using clone() don't you think it should be implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to provide your own `clone` or a copy constructor as part of the `Hello` class.

E.g. (`clone`):

```
public Hello clone() {
    Hello h;

    h = new Hello();
    h.mesg1 = this.mesg1;
    h.mesg2 = this.mesg2;
    h.c = this.c; // Or a deep copy if appropriate
    h.d = this.d; // Or a deep copy if appropriate

    return h;
}
```

or (copy constructor):

```
public Hello(Hello original) {
    this.mesg1 = original.mesg1;
    this.mesg2 = original.mesg2;
    this.c = original.c; // Or a deep copy if appropriate
    this.d = original.d; // Or a deep copy if appropriate
}
```

Then use it

```
a[5] = new Hello();
// set its members
a[1] = a[5].clone(); // or = new Hello(a[5]);
// set its members
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to clone/duplicate an existing object, and modify the duplicate, without changing the code of `Hello.class`?

If you can create a new instance of the Hello class by using one of it's constructors, that would be the easiest solution. Some of the data structures have so called copy constructors, for example like this:

```
Hello original = new Hello();
Hello duplicate = new Hello(original);
```

If the class does not have such a constructor, you may try creating a new instance by using reflection. There are some libraries which can clone objects and or copy their properties from one object to another, for example:

```
Hello duplicate = BeanUtils.instantiate(original.getClass());
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(original, duplicate);
```

Or even easier, the utility method of commons-lang:

```
Hello duplicate = org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.clone(original);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom clone method for `Hello` class if the object is not too big, like this:

```
static Hello cloneHello(Hello h){
  Hello newHello = new Hello();
  //for primitive and immutable types
  newHello.setMsg1(h.getMsg1());
  newHello.setMsg1(h.getMsg2());

  //for mutable objects you can provide cloneMyObject(MyObject o) for each type
  newHello.setMyObject(cloneMyObject(h.getMyObject()));

  //and so on ..

  return newHello;
}
```

This can get tedious but should do the trick.

If you cannot make new instance of `Hello` then you'll have to use serialisation as suggested by others.

Comment: Yes Guys, thanks for answer. I have used a copy Constructor and it works great.